# Delphi 2010 - How to Copy and Clear the TShape

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-2010, shapes

Ok, after working with TShape, I need to clean my "Shape1" from Lines and Text.

And also how to copy everything in "Shape1" into "Shape2" ?

Thanks B4 ^o^

```
    type
      TShape = class(ExtCtrls.TShape); //interposer class

      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Shape1: TShape;
        Shape2: TShape;
        Button1: TButton;
        Button2: TButton;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
      public
      end;

    var
      Form1: TForm1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
//        Draw some text on Shape1 := TShape 
        Shape1.Canvas.Font.Name :='Arial';// set the font 
        Shape1.Canvas.Font.Size  :=20;//set the size of the font
        Shape1.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlue;//set the color of the text
        Shape1.Canvas.TextOut(10,10,'1999');
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
//        Copy everything from Shape1 to Shape2 (make a duplication)
//        How to do it ? 
        showmessage('copy Shape1 into Shape2');    
    end;

    End.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following pseudo-code makes a copy of `SourceShape` canvas content to the `TargetShape` canvas, but only until the `TargetShape` is refreshed:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TargetShape.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, TargetShape.ClientWidth,
    TargetShape.ClientHeight), SourceShape.Canvas, Rect(0, 0,
    SourceShape.ClientWidth, SourceShape.ClientHeight));
end;
```

To *clear* the previously copied content, you can use the following:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TargetShape.Invalidate;
end;
```

To keep your drawing persistent you need to implement your own `OnPaint` event, in which whenever it fires, copy the current canvas content from the source to target using the [`CopyRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.CopyRect) method like shown above.

But the question is then, why to use a `TShape` control at all. It would be better to use `TPaintBox` and draw your stuff by yourself including the shapes that are drawn by `TShape` control.

Comment: Previously, I know the TImage and TShape only... But thank you for telling me the TPaintBox... I'll try it :)